# Fire PreSaveItem () on infopath form "Save" button

Tags: infopath

I have edit form and it is created using Infopath .When i am trying to use PreSaveItem ()  when Click on "Save" button it is not firing ?Why?

How to fire PreSaveItem ()  on InfoPath Form "Save" button ?